# Error on coefficients returned by polyfit in python

Tags: python

I am trying to fit a line between two points with y errors associated to them, I know how to obtain the coefficients but not their errors.

```
p ,c= np.polyfit([x[0], x[-1]], [y1, y2],1, w = [y1_error, y2_error], cov=True)
errors = np.sqrt(np.diag(c))
```

Edit - I just need a way to quantify the possibility that the line could be drawn differently because of the wide range of values y can take

I am getting the following error for the first line:
    ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,2) (0)

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: You can always plot a line connecting two points, what do you mean by errors then?

Comment: The points have errors so the line could be drawn between the extremes of these. I just need a way to quantify the possibility that the line could be drawn differently because of the wide range of values y can take

Comment: Looks like you're using some kind of library; care to identify which?